# Can I make Stage Manager work somewhat differently?

Tags: ventura, stage-manager

I know how Stage Manager works, but I want to make work differently.

The default works like this: when I choose one of group in the `Cast` Part, then all apps are hidden and all apps open up in the `Stage` Part which are apps in the selected group.

And I want to make like this: when I choose one of group in the `Cast` Part, then all apps remain as is, and all apps open up in the `Stage` Part which are apps in the selected group.

Comment: That's very unclear to me. What are you exactly trying to do? What is the "Cast Part" and "Stage Part"?

Comment: Sorry for that. I saw this article https://eclecticlight.co/2022/09/12/why-venturas-stage-manager-is-so-important/ they use terms like that but it seems uncommon.
When it’s active, each display consists of two zones: the Stage in the centre, where your active app(s) and their windows are, and a Cast at the left edge, containing other apps and their windows, poised to come on Stage whenever you want them.

Comment: It's unlikely that you can 'make' a feature work in a different way that hasn't been accommodated by the coders.